# Why aren't pictures in imessages showing up on my macbook messages?

Tags: photos, messages

I setup my macbook to show messages from my iphone conversations and they show up now but none of the pictures show up.  I see a reference to a picture but i can't view it or download it.

**NOTE**: I am able to send pictures from my macbook messages directly and those work fine.

I have plenty of storage available on my computer so not sure what the reason could be.

[image]

if I click on download arrow or double click on the image this is all I see

[image]

Can anyone else determine why I can't see pictures on my macbook within messages when it was sent from my iphone.

Comment: best guess, the down arrow to the right is saying it's not downloaded yet. Try clicking it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - clicking on the down arrow doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Any solution? Having the same issue!

Comment: I also have the same question.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I had an empty file at /Users/name/Library/Messages/Attachments, even though that's supposed to be a folder where all of your images get stored. Once I deleted the blank file, photos started working. There's a related discussion here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601288.